# Elastic search down after several months

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a elastic search cluster with 2 nodes running on a 2 cores CPU 8GB ram instance. Each node has the argument "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms3g -Xmx3g" passed in. I have 4 indices each has 2 shards and 1 replica. After 2 months, it went down. Checked the instance monitoring, not seeing any CPU or memory spike. Disk has plenty of free space. Checked the es log. The only thing I see is

```
[gc][2845340] overhead, spent [339ms] collecting in the last [1s]
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the garbage collector starts reporting that it spends ~30% of the time collecting, it usually means that there's not enough heap anymore.

You should increase the heap a little bit until the GC stops reporting. You can increase the heap up to half the available memory, but not more than 30GB

To this end, change the setting below, and make sure that `Xms` is always equals to `Xmx` and never goes over 30.

```
ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms4g -Xmx4g
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. There is only 8gb ram on the instance. If I change to 4gb for each node and I have 2 nodes. Would it run out of memory given the OS will reserve some memory ?

Comment: Ok then the issue is that if you have 8GB of RAM on the instance and two nodes on that instance, then you should only allocate 2GB per node. That's most probably the reason why you're seeing increased garbage collection, i.e. because you're short on heap. That being said, it's generally  a bad idea to run two nodes on the same instance and they will always end up competing for resources.